# Is smoke from oil lamp dangerous

Tags: lungs, nose, environmental-conditions, smoke-inhalation, toxic-fumes

There was a power outage recently in my flat, so I decided to light up some older oil lamp I found. I didn't notice that as the wick was probably too large, the lamp was smoking whole night. When I woke up the next day I figured out that everything was covered in a black dust that probably was caused by this smoke.

My nose was also full of this and I guess my lungs are as well.

Is this sort of dust from oil lamp dangerous? Could I poison myself or damage my lungs?

Comment: What kind of oil was in the lamp? Anything else than oil was burning in the lamp?